# Why doesn't ObservableCollection implement IList?

Tags: c#, observablecollection, ilist

I have a `Type` of `{System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection}` and it implements the following interfaces

[image]

This is my code to check if the type implements `IList`

```
if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IList<>)))
{
    type = type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
    enclosedType = EnclosedType.List;
}
```

Why doesn't this work?
I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: [IList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist(v=vs.110).aspx) and [IList<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6(v=vs.110).aspx) are two different interfaces.

Comment: ``System.Collection.Generic.IList`1[MusicTracker.Model.Track]`` (or `System.Collection.Generic.IList<MusicTracker.Model.Track>` in C# notation) is not the same as ``System.Collection.Generic.IList`1[T]`` (C# `System.Collection.Generic.IList<>`). One is a closed generic type, and the other is a generic type definition. And both are unrelated to the non-generic `System.Collections.IList`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As stated below. It implements `IList<TheType>` and not `IList`
You need to check the generic type definitions for the interfaces.

Example:

```
type.GetInterfaces()
    .Where(i => i.IsGenericType)
    .Select(i => i.GetGenericTypeDefinition())
    .Contains(typeof(IList<>));
```